# Points on $ \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$ expressed as $n\times n$ matrices | geometric interpetanion of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbf{R}) $

Tags: matrices, manifolds, lie-groups

How exactly does this works because I didn't found any explanation.
If I take the $3\times3$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &1 \\ 
 3& 0 &7 \\ 
 2&  5&9 
\end{pmatrix}$ the point would be $(1,2,1,3,0,7,2,5)$ ? Like following the $a_{ij }$ order

Also, $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbf{R}) = \left\{A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix} :\, \det A = ad-bc \ne 0\right\}$ can someone help understand how this forms a manifold (does it even have a shape, a geometric intuition?) what's is the map from $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbf{R})\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you agree that$$M=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb R^4\mid ad\ne bc\}$$is a $4$-dimensional manifold. So, consider the bijection$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Psi\colon&M&\longrightarrow&GL(2,\mathbf R)\\&(a,b,c,d)&\mapsto&\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.\end{array}$$Then, since it is a bijection whose domain is a manifold, $\Psi$ induces a manifold structure on $GL(2,\mathbf R)$. If you want to, say, check that $\exp\colon GL(2,\mathbf R)\longrightarrow\mathbf R$ is differentiable, you can say that it is, since $\exp\circ\Psi$ is differentiable.

Comment: The map is the identity ?

Comment: No, since it is a map from a subset of $\Bbb R^4$ into a set of $2\times2$ real matrices. Unless you identify the set of such matrices with $\Bbb R^4$, but I don't think that that's a common option.

Comment: I get what you mean now, thanks.

Comment: Define the map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ by sending $(a_{11},\ldots,a_{1n},a_{21}\ldots,a_{2n},\ldots,a_{n1}\ldots,a_{nn})\mapsto\operatorname{det}(a_{ij})$. Then $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n^2})=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$

Comment: @PetrosK: Notice that the map $f:\mathbb{R}^4\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ given by $(a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22})\mapsto\operatorname{det}(a_{ij})$ is smooth and that $GL(2)=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$. The manifold structure (in terms of atlases) then is easy to get.